# Handle a folder like paperclip "system" folder, symlinked in shared

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip, capistrano

I have a folder of uploaded assets (through paperclip) by a gem, which are stored in a different folder `ckeditor_assets`.

I would like to handle this folder with capistrano in the exact same way the `system` folder is handled for paperclip uploads.

How can I achieve this? It will contain clients data, so it's important.

Comment: I'm still trying to set a different path on ckeditor gem so I can move the folder directly to "shared"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with this: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/02/capistrano-uploads-folder/

For future reference, I report a part of the blogpost which basically creates a directory in capistrano `shared` folder and symlink it each time.

```
# ==============================
# Uploads
# ==============================

namespace :uploads do

  desc <<-EOD
    Creates the upload folders unless they exist
    and sets the proper upload permissions.
  EOD
  task :setup, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    dirs = uploads_dirs.map { |d| File.join(shared_path, d) }
    run "#{try_sudo} mkdir -p #{dirs.join(' ')} && #{try_sudo} chmod g+w #{dirs.join(' ')}"
  end

  desc <<-EOD
    [internal] Creates the symlink to uploads shared folder
    for the most recently deployed version.
  EOD
  task :symlink, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "rm -rf #{release_path}/public/uploads"
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public/uploads"
  end

  desc <<-EOD
    [internal] Computes uploads directory paths
    and registers them in Capistrano environment.
  EOD
  task :register_dirs do
    set :uploads_dirs,    %w(uploads uploads/partners)
    set :shared_children, fetch(:shared_children) + fetch(:uploads_dirs)
  end

  after       "deploy:finalize_update", "uploads:symlink"
  on :start,  "uploads:register_dirs"

end
```

Please see the blogpost for multistaging support and some instructions.

Comment: I followed this way to upload ckeditor_assets in shared folder . Still I am unable to upload. My images are being deleted.. Can u help me to fix this out?

Comment: I think it's better if you make a new question because without details there is nothing I can do.

Comment: Thanks @Fire-Dragon-DoL for your reply.. I have resolved the issue. It was just a permission issue.